# Abscissa of convergence of a Dirichlet series with bounded coefficients and analytic continuation

Tags: convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

If a Dirichlet series has coefficients +1 and -1 and an analytic continuation without poles (or zeros) to the right of Re(s) = 1/2, what can we say about it's abscissa of convergence?

Is it always at most (at or to the left of) 1/2? Would it help if the coefficients are multiplicative?
*And this is a normal dirichlet series, so each term is n^-x

A motivation is the reciprocal zeta series, where the abscissa of convergence can be determined by knowing up to where the analytic continuation doesn't have poles (Riemann hypothesis bounds the Mertens function to o(sqrt(n)n^ε)).

*Actually my original functions must have an Euler product of (1+p^-x)(1-p^-x)(1+0p^-x) for the primes divided into two subgroups, the remaining primes ignored. I think my statement can be proven if my functions' equivalent of a prime zeta function converges (at least to 1/2) which can be proven if my functions' number of zeros satisfy a similar asymptomatic bound as the zeta function. Namely the sum of (1/r+1/r*)  converges (I think it must be absolutely) where this sum goes over the reciprocal of each root/zero of my function and with multiplicacy -1 over each pole, and each is paired with its complex conjugate. Can this be proven?

Comment: Not sure, but if RH is true, then $\eta(s)=\zeta(s)(1-2^{1-s})=\sum{(-1)^nn^{-s}}$ should be a counter-example (the convergence abscissa is zero).

Comment: There is an old result about "random" $\pm 1$ coefficiented Dirichlet series having natural boundaries... Sadly, at this moment I can't recall either the details or the author: H. Bohr?

Comment: I meant the abscissa is at most 1/2, not at least 1/2. I have fixed my question.

Comment: I found some papers on random Dirichlet series with good results, though all of them were probibalistic, so along the lines of something is true for almost all such series. This doesn't exclude exceptions unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for the abscissa of convergence to be anything between $0$ and $1$.

To see that it can be as small as $0$, note that the Dirichlet series
$$ \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^s} $$
has abscissa of convergence equal to $0$.

It is clear that $1$ is possible, from $\zeta(s)$, and standard coefficient bounds guarantee that the abscissa cannot be greater than $1$.

The fact any abscissa of convergence between $0$ and $1$ is possible follows from the fact that for any $\theta \in (0, 1)$, one can choose signs $\epsilon_i \in \{ -1, +1 \}$ such that
$$ \sum_{n \leq N} \epsilon_i \asymp N^\theta. $$
Abel summation then shows that $\theta$ is the abscissa of convergence.

Comment: The zeta function isn't a counterexample because it's analytic continuation has a pole at 1 and my hypothetical function has no singularities after 1/2. A counterexample must be a function whose analytic continuation has no singularities up to 1/2 but an abscissa of convergence greater than 1/2

Comment: As in an earlier comment, $(1-2^{1-s})\cdot \zeta(s)$ gets rid of the pole at $1$...

Comment: The abscissa of convergence of this function is not greater than 1/2 so it is not a counterexample.

Comment: You're right, I did not use that the OP has analytic continuation to $\mathrm{Re} s > 1/2$. I'll have to think about that.

Comment: For the reciprocal zeta function it is proved using proved asymptomatic density of the zeros. My function must have an Euler product of the form (1+p1^-x)(1-p2^-x) for two distinct subsets of the primes (would it being multiplicative help). Using the Mellon inversion formula for an analog of the explicit formula for the chebyshiev and prime counting function (in these ones the first subset of primes contribute with a negative sign and the second contribute with a positive). In this way if we can prove a similar asymptomatic density for a general such series, we can prove

Comment: the convergence of +p1^-x - p2^-x or the analog of the prime zeta function, but here one subset of the primes is with positive sign, the second is with negative, and the remaining primes are ignored (have a 0 in front of them). I'm somewhat sure that this implies the convergence of the original dirichlet series, as if this is P(s), the sum of P(ns)/n is the original function, but even if it doesn't I'm satisfied with P(s) converging to 1/2. In summary I think what I want is that it's zeros obey the same asymptomatic bounds as those of the zeta function and I'll edit my question accordingly.